# Fourier transform of $\sin(2\pi ft)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a function $\sin(2\pi\cdot f\cdot t)$ where $t$ is the time domain and $f$ is the frequency.I must represent the fourier transform of this function in polar and cylindrical coordinates.
I can tell you how did I proceed but i don't know if it's ok.
I made the $\operatorname{fft}(\sin(2\pi\cdot f\cdot t))$ and I used $[\theta,r]=\operatorname{cart2pol}(x,y)$ function to obtain $r$ and $\theta$. $x$ and $y$ are the cartesian coordinates.
My question is: who is $x$ and who is $y$ in my case? i chose $x$ the frequency and $y$ the amplitude. Is this ok?

Comment: you remind me of myself....

Comment: *I can tell you how did I proceed but i don't know if it's ok.* <- Doesn't matter. Just show how you tried to proceed.

Comment: A more informative title would be nice!

Comment: is the first time i write a post and i didn't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Help $cart2pol$. Your signal has a frequency $f_0$ not $f$. It is a $1D$ time signal with sinusoidal amplitude. When you transform it you will get a Dirac function at $f=f_0$. Your function then will have an amplitude and frequency. I woul guess only that $x=f_0$ and $y=1$ for $cart2pol$

Comment: I understood.thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Toader my pleasure. If you liked this site and want to ask more questions, then I can suggest you to check "http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/". You can search there some faq s especially about "how to ask a question", "what to ask and what not to ask". "which sort of formatting is used to type a question", "how to type in tex", "what do upvoting, downvoting and accepting an answer mean?", "what sort of style we should follow when we ask a question, etc..". Welcome again to MSE.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for the advice.I would like  to ask you one more question.I have to represent the fourier transform for a 2D signal, for exemple sin(2*x+3*y).who are x and y and how can I obtain this graphically?Thanks a lot.